Odoo add two Many2one fields on same model cause error
I need to add two Many2one fields in res.partner model and both are linked to res.partner.
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    
    field1 = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
    field2 = fields.Many2one('res.partner')

But that causes an error :
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 2: ...rtner__field2" ON ("res_partner"."field2" = "res_par...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. 

Would you have an idea of the reason of this error ?
Thanks

Are you sure that's all the code which leads to this error?

Yes, the code is longer but it is the field2 that causes the error because when I change to field2= fields.Char() everything works fine

Can you provide some more context? I've just created an addon with two res.partner M2O fields on res.partner (like you did) and it works without any issues in my local environment (Odoo Server 17.0-20240826)

I'm very sorry that was a typo error

Ok it was a typo error and now it works. Thanks for your help !
